# Is it possible to assign F3 to search in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, shortcut

I use Rclipse for Java where for used Ctrl+F for search, but F3 seems is a standard for search. I would like use F3 shortcut, but also if I assign F3 to work like Ctrl+F - it opens dialog windows for search and replace. Is it possible use F3 like in Notepad++?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. From the preference panel you have to bind F3 to `Find and Replace` feature :

[image: screenshot]

You must avoid conflicts with other command to make it work ...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the step

Start Eclipse

go to **Window > Preferences**

Select the **General > Editor > Keys** page

search a command "Find" from grid. which has a shortcut Ctrl + F.

click **Copy command**

Set Binding property to **F3**

That's it...

Answer (score 2):

You can bind <kbd>F3</kbd> to `Incremental Find` (`Ctrl+J`)